# Lua - calculating if a time is between two time stamps

Tags: lua

Given the following examples:

```
--Test current     start     end     between
--1    10:00       09:00     12:00   true
--2    01:00       07:34     09:54   false
--3    17:00       16:00     03:00   true
--4    10:00       10:00     15:00   true
--5    10:30       10:00     10:30   true
```

In Lua, how is it best to create a function that I can call:

```
BetweenTimes ("10:00", "09:00","12:00")
```

and in this case (Test 1) return true.  The issue I have is will Test case 3.

I can assume that the first time is always before the second time.

I think this might be it:

```
local function parse_time(str)
   local hour, min = str:match("(%d+):(%d+)")
   return os.time{hour = hour, min = min, day = 1, month = 1, year = 1970}
end

local function BetweenTimes(between, start, stop)
   between = parse_time(between)
   start   = parse_time(start)
   stop    = parse_time(stop)

   if stop < start then
      return (start <= between) or (between <= stop)
   else
      return (start <= between) and (between <= stop)
   end
end

print(BetweenTimes("10:00", "09:00", "12:00")) -- true
print(BetweenTimes("15:00", "09:00", "12:00")) -- false
print(BetweenTimes("15:00", "09:00", "01:00")) -- true
print(BetweenTimes("10:00", "10:00", "11:00")) -- true
print(BetweenTimes("11:00", "10:00", "11:00")) -- true
print(BetweenTimes("19:00", "17:00", "03:30")) -- true
print(BetweenTimes("03:00", "04:00", "05:30")) -- false
print(BetweenTimes("03:00", "02:00", "05:30")) -- true
print(BetweenTimes("01:00", "09:00", "02:30")) -- true
```

or even just the following should work to remove `os.time()`:

```
local function BetweenTimes(between, start, stop)
   local start   = string.gsub(start,":", "")
   local between = string.gsub(between,":", "") 
   local stop    = string.gsub(stop,":", "") 

   if stop < start then
      return (start <= between) or (between <= stop)
   else
      return (start <= between) and (between <= stop)
   end
end
```

Comment: Does `BetweenTimes ("01:00", "09:00","02:00")` return true?

Comment: @lhf Thanks for pointing this out, it does return false when it should return true.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach sounds overly complicated.  Just parse the hours and minutes out of the string and convert it to a UNIX timestamp.  These are regular integers and you can easily compare them using `<` and `>`.

```
local function parse_time(str)
   local hour, min = str:match("(%d+):(%d+)")
   return os.time{hour = hour, min = min, day = 1, month = 1, year = 1970}
end

local function BetweenTimes(between, start, stop)
   between = parse_time(between)
   start   = parse_time(start)
   stop    = parse_time(stop)
   if stop < start then
      stop = stop + 24*60*60 -- add 24 h
   end
   return (start <= between) and (between <= stop)
end

print(BetweenTimes("10:00", "09:00", "12:00")) -- true
print(BetweenTimes("15:00", "09:00", "12:00")) -- false
print(BetweenTimes("15:00", "09:00", "01:00")) -- true
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What about this case:
`print(BetweenTimes("15:00", "09:00", "01:00"))`
I would like for this to return true as 15:00 is between 9AM and 1AM, where the start time >= stop time.

Comment: @HelpingHand What? 15:00 is certainly *not* between 01:00 and 09:00.  At least not on the same day.

Comment: @HelpingHand I added wrapping around by 24 h if `stop` is before `start`.

Comment: Thanks for this, really helpful.  It passes all the test cases I have.  I had a rough idea of what needed to be done.  I was interest to hear from someone more familiar with LUA as to the right/easiest way.  Thanks again.

Comment: @HelpingHand I'll leave this as an exercise to you ;) I'm sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even using the date when you only have hours and minutes? Unless you expect to handle any other time units in future, a simple multiplication will suffice.

```
local function parse_time(str)
   local hour, min = str:match("(%d+):(%d+)")
   return min * 60 + hour
end
```

I won't copy `BetweenTimes` from Henri Menke's answer - it is exactly the same with the only change inside wrapping handling because my `parse_time` returns minutes, not seconds:

```
stop = stop + 24*60
```